# Is it possible to initialize an empty OrderedDict in Python with a predefined sorting mechanism?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ordereddictionary

All examples I could find ([in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), etc.) define OrderedDicts by passing data to the constructor. From the docs:

```
# regular unsorted dictionary
d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}

# dictionary sorted by key
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])
```

On the other hand, it is possible to initialize an OrderedDict by providing no parameters to the constructor, which leads it to preserve the order in which key,value pairs are added.

I am looking for a kind of construct that resembles the following, except without "d.items()". Essentially, I'm asking it to remember a mechanism without providing it an example, which might sound crazy. Is my only option to "hack" this by providing an initial "d" (below) with a single item, or is there a better way?

```
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's the default behaviour?

Comment: Sorted Dictionaries don't re-sort their contents on insertion. They remember insertion order and can be sorted, but they don't just auto-sort when adding keys.  For that you're looking for something like a SortedCollection.  IIRC there's a recipe for one (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/) that uses the bisect module, but the OrderedDict isn't enough on its own.

Comment: You might be able to roll your own, perhaps consider using a [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#module-heapq) to preserve the ordering internally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OrderedDict` only has one sorting algorithm: insertion order.  Whatever order the items are added to the `OrderedDict` is the order the `OrderedDict` has.

If you want some other method you can either write your `dict` subclass or just write a sort function that you can apply when the order is actually important.